# How to clear cache from django database in version 2.1?

Tags: python, django, caching

I am facing weird issue, after wasting so much time I found out that this is the problem because of Database cache.
I made a Model Name "Profile" later flushdb / deleted it.

After few hours I made it again but getting this error
**"No such column"** 
then I removed all sql3db files *.pyc file etc,
& run my model again (so django will recreate db structure {also performed migrate &  makemigrations}).

But still same error,

then I just renamed my db & the same code working now fine.

My problem is I have to use that old Old Model name again
but not able to get because of db cache (or maybe something)

please guide me.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profiles
admin.site.register(Profiles)
```

my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profiles(models.Model):
    # p2=  models.CharField(max_length=14)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    username2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note: I have tried all old solution available on this web,
but in my case not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this django documentation link,it will surly helps you.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/

here are the basic related queries,it may helpful for understanding.

```
# You can delete keys explicitly with delete(). This is an easy way of clearing the 
#cache for a particular object:
#cache.delete(key, version=None)
#cache.delete_many(['a', 'b', 'c'])
#cache.clear()
```

Comment: will it work? because i have no table with this name, so what key then i remove